# Sabre Enhanced Air Ticket show authentication error in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I had in contact with sabre and they provided me IPCC code , user id and password in separate email . i don't know where to put those credentials either in my code or in my account or the way i am accessing the request is not correct. your help will be appreciated.

Here is my code below:

```
$client_id= base64_encode("client_id"); // my id 
$client_secret = base64_encode("secret_key");// secret key in my account
$token = base64_encode($client_id.":".$client_secret);

$data='grant_type=client_credentials';


    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: Basic '.$token,
        'Accept: */*',
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.sabre.com/v2/auth/token");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $resf = json_decode($res,1);
    $access_token = $resf['key']; // long string key that i got from sabre after clicking request production key
    $token_type = $resf['token_type'];
    $expires_in_seconds = $resf['expires_in'];

    // //  END get access token 

    // now to get api data using the provided access token
    $url = 'https://api.havail.sabre.com/v1.2.0/air/ticket';
    $headers2 = array(
    'Authorization: bearer '.$access_token,
    'protocol: HTTP 1.1 ',
    "Content-Type: application/json"
     );

$postData ='{
  "AirTicketRQ": {
    "DesignatePrinter": {
      "Profile": {
        "Number": 1
      }
    },
    "Itinerary": {
      "ID": "VWKJJT"
    },
    "Ticketing": [{
      "FOP_Qualifiers": {
        "BSP_Ticketing": {
          "MultipleFOP": {
            "Fare": {
              "Amount": "100.00"
            },
            "FOP_One": {
              "CC_Info": {
                "Suppress": true,
                "PaymentCard": {
                  "Code": "VI",
                  "ExpireDate": "2016-11",
                  "ExtendedPayment": 12,
                  "Number": 573912345621003
                }
              }
            },
            "FOP_Two": {
              "Type": "CK"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "PricingQualifiers": {
        "PriceQuote": [{
          "Record": [{
            "Number": 1,
            "Reissue": true
          }]
        }]
      }
    },
    {
      "FOP_Qualifiers": {
        "BSP_Ticketing": {
          "MultipleFOP": {
            "Fare": {
              "Amount": "100.00"
            },
            "FOP_One": {
              "CC_Info": {
                "Suppress": true,
                "PaymentCard": {
                  "Code": "VI",
                  "ExpireDate": "2016-11",
                  "ExtendedPayment": 12,
                  "Number": 443212345621003
                }
              }
            },
            "FOP_Two": {
              "Type": "CA"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "PricingQualifiers": {
        "PriceQuote": [{
          "Record": [{
            "Number": 2,
            "Reissue": true
          }]
        }]
      }
    }],
    "PostProcessing": {
      "EndTransaction": {
        "Source": {
          "ReceivedFrom": "SPTEST"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}';

$ch2 = curl_init();


curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers2);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

var_dump( $results = json_decode(curl_exec($ch2),true));
```

in response i am getting this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEOEV.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its explained here quite well: https://developer.sabre.com/page/read/resources/getting_started_with_sabre_apis/how_to_get_a_token

```
POST https://api.havail.sabre.com/v2/auth/token HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, 
like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36
Origin: chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
Authorization: Basic  
VmpFNmRYTmxjbWxrT21keWIzVndPbVJ2YldGcGJnPT06TVRJek5EVT0=
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: */*
grant_type: client_credentials
```

How 
VmpFNmRYTmxjbWxrT21keWIzVndPbVJ2YldGcGJnPT06TVRJek5EVT0= is built is described here: https://developer.sabre.com/resources/getting_started_with_sabre_apis/sabre_apis_101/how_to_guides/rest_apis_token_credentials